# Couldn't load module web in openERP7 installation on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, odoo, openerp-7

I needed to install openERP 7 but I only have ubuntu 10.04 available. I have used `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/python-unittest2/ubuntu lucid main` to install python-unittest2 on ubuntu 10.04 to have all the dependencies required by openerp.

I have followed the [theopensourcerer.com](http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2012/12/how-to-install-openerp-7-0-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) tutorial so it get the tarball of the latest build.
the path is /opt/openerp/server. below is my configuration

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = openerp
db_password = mypassword
logfile = /var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log
```

When I run this command: /opt/openerp/server/openerp-server I have the error: `No handler found.` On the web side and I have on the system log the error below:

```
2014-03-06 19:35:54,372 14586 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 7.0-20140306-001044
2014-03-06 19:35:54,372 14586 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: /opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons
2014-03-06 19:35:54,372 14586 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost
2014-03-06 19:35:54,372 14586 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
2014-03-06 19:35:54,372 14586 INFO ? openerp: database user: openerp
2014-03-06 19:35:54,427 14586 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: Couldn't load module web
2014-03-06 19:35:54,428 14586 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: No module named wsgi
2014-03-06 19:35:54,428 14586 ERROR ? openerp.service: Failed to load server-wide module `web`.
The `web` module is provided by the addons found in the `openerp-web` project.
Maybe you forgot to add those addons in your addons_path configuration.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/service/__init__.py", line 60, in load_server_wide_modules
openerp.modules.module.load_openerp_module(m)
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/modules/module.py", line 405, in load_openerp_module
__import__('openerp.addons.' + module_name)
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/modules/module.py", line 133, in load_module
mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
import http
File "/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 32, in <module>
import werkzeug.wsgi
ImportError: No module named wsgi 
2014-03-06 19:35:54,437 14586 INFO ? openerp.service.wsgi_server: HTTP service  (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
2014-03-06 19:35:54,437 14586 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP server is running, waiting for connections...
```

When I checked `/var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log` I read :

```
2014-03-06 17:20:20,674 13160 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 7.0-20140306-001044
2014-03-06 17:20:20,674 13160 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/openerp/addons
//....
```

The message is similar to the one above but paths are changed to `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/openerp/addons`

So I editted the configuration file by including both `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/openerp/addons` and `/opt/openerp/server/openerp/addons` and restarted openerp but it didn't help.

Has anyone succeeded in installing openERP 7 on ubuntu 10.04? Help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: might be your `web` module is mis-placed. when web module run than it will find web module but can't find path of web. And import werkzeug.wsgi no issue. See your web __init__.py file it's gives import http. So I think may be issue of your web module.

Answer (score 3):

just install werkzeug module. your error indicates that werkzeug module is not installed. here is the command, run on terminal. `sudo apt-get install python-werkzeug` . or you can also install it through easy install like this - `sudo easy_install Werkzeug` . and then restart the server.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Although my issues was for some other module, but this answer guided me in right direction. Getting further errors though, but this particular problem is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solve it with [this tutorial](http://solyblog.solydev.net/acticle/installer-la-version-7-saas2-dopenerp)

You must add this line in your configuration file :

addons_path = /opt/openerp/addons,/opt/openerp/web/addons

it work fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check the user has by which you are running openerp has all needed rights ?
if it has and still throwing an error then you should follow [this](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/help-1/question/openerp-service-failed-to-load-server-wide-module-web-89384).